# $\frac{X_1+...+X_{n-1}-\log n }{\sqrt{\log n} }\rightarrow N(0,1)$ where $X_n\sim \operatorname{Ber}(\log \frac{n+1}{n})$

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

> Prove : $\frac{X_1+...+X_{n-1}-\log n }{\sqrt{\log n} }\rightarrow N(0,1)$ 
> where $X_n\sim \operatorname{Ber}({\lambda}_n)$  and $\lambda _n = \log \frac{n+1}{n}$

I tried using a similar proof to CLT with characteristic function but didnt manage to get there. Here is my attempt:

$$ S_n = X_1 +...+X_n$$
$$\varphi_{\frac{S_{n-1}-\log n }{\sqrt{\log n} }}(t)=\varphi_{S_{n-1}-\log n}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\log n}})$$
$$\varphi_{X_i-\lambda _i}=(\lambda _ie^{it}+1-\lambda _i)e^{-it\lambda _i}$$

So I get a multiplacation of $\varphi_{X_i-\lambda _i}(t/\sqrt(\log n))$ and I don't see why it should go to $e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}$

I might add that I don't know any representation of e as a form of an infinite changing multiplication, so I don't see how this way would lead me to the solution.

Thank you,

Comment: The question in the title is different to the one in the main body.

Comment: What do you mean? I might miss something

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it

Comment: It was still unclear how you wanted $\lambda$ to be defined. I've made another edit, please check to see if it is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y_{n}=X_{n}-\log(\frac{n+1}{n})$ . Then $\operatorname{Var}(Y_{n})=\operatorname{Var}(X_{n})=(1-\log(\frac{n+1}{n}))\log(\frac{n+1}{n})$.

Then $\displaystyle \operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\operatorname{Var}(Y_{k})=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-\log(\frac{k+1}{k}))\log(\frac{k+1}{k})$

Now it can be proven by applying Stolz-Cesaro's Theorem that $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1-\log(\frac{k+1}{k}))\log(\frac{k+1}{k})}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(\frac{k+1}{k})}\to 1$$

Or just observe that $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{2}(1+1/k)}{\log(n+1)}\to 0$$ as $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{2}(1+1/k)$ is a convergent series by comparison with $\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}$ to show that the above limit tends to 1.

This gives that $\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})\sim\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(\frac{k+1}{k})= \log(n+1)$

Thus, if we can verify [Lindeberg's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) that $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{n})}^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E(Y_{k}^{2}\mathbf{1}_{|Y_{k}|>t\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})}})\to 0$ for all $t>0$ , then you will have by the Lindeberg-Feller CLT that $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{n}}{\sqrt{\log(n)}}\xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$ by an application of Slutsky's theorem.

So we try and verify [Liapunov's condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447518/intuitive-explanation-of-lyapunov-condition-for-clt#:%7E:text=Lyapunov%20condition%20is%20one%20way,condition%20bears%20on%20their%20moments.) i.e. show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\displaystyle\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}E(|X_{k}|^{2+\delta})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})}^{2+\delta}}\to 0$

Now,
$(\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}))^{2}\sim\log^{2}(n+1)$.

So we show that for $\delta=2$, we have

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}E(|Y_{k}|^{4})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})}^{4}}\to 0$$

Thus, Liapunov's Condition will be satisfied. Thus, by Lindeberg-Feller CLT, you have that $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{n}}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})}}\xrightarrow{d}N(0,1)$ which is what we wanted to show. Now as $\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})\sim\log(n+1)$ , we have by Slutsky's theorem that $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{n}}{\sqrt{\log(n)}}\xrightarrow{d}N(0,1) $

$ \blacksquare$

Now, to show that  $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}E(|Y_{k}|^{4})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k})}^{4}}\sim\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}E(|Y_{k}|^{4})}{\log^{2}(n+1)}\to 0$$.

We first see that $$E|Y_{k}|^{4}=(1-\log(\frac{k+1}{k}))^{4}\log(\frac{k+1}{k})+\log^{4}(\frac{k+1}{k})(1-\log(\frac{k+1}{k}))$$.

But again we have that $$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log^{m}(1+\frac{1}{k})}{\log^{2}(n+1)}\to 0$$

for all $m> 1$ as the series $\sum_{k}\log^{m}(1+\frac{1}{k})$ is convergent by comparison with $\sum_{k}\frac{1}{k^{m}}$.

Thus by expanding the numerator, we will only be left with $$\displaystyle\frac{2\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(\frac{k+1}{k})}{\log^{2}(n+1)}=\frac{2\cdot\log(n+1)}{\log^{2}(n+1)}\to 0$$ Thus, we have shown Liapunov's condition.

$ \blacksquare$

For references on Lindegerg-Feller CLT,Liapunov's condition etc see [Sidney Resnick, A Probability Path](https://www.academia.edu/31852080/A_probabilitv_Path_Sidney_I_Resnick_BIRKHAUSER) section 9.8 page 314.

Comment: Thank you,
I want to point out for future people who come that there is a solution without using Lindeberg's condition. Look at "Probability with Martingales" David William page 189. The solution uses characteristic function

Comment: @OrenDiskin You can use your method itself to conclude that. In that case, it'll become a highschool problem in limits (not an easy one). To avoid those, you can use an established result like Lindeberg CLT. Otherwise, you have to show the convergence of the characteristic functions. I initially thought of going down that road. But got discouraged when I saw a very complicated limit that was appearing.